# woocommerce product save / refresh / update php code after insert products automatically / programatically

Tags: php, woocommerce, save, product

I need some help from the woocommerce experts!
Have an php script for automatically / programatically insert of products.
In the backend it looks all fine after insert, but in the frontend there is no connecting to the categorie side bar. Looked so much time on DB for finding out the reason, but couldn't find it till now. If I save / refresh / update only one product in the backend per categorie by hand, so all the other products from the categories are will be placed at categorie side bar in frontend.
Cause of this reason I'm looking for a php code for "save/refresh/update" the products, wich I can insert to cronjob, who can run after programatically product insert.

Comment: What does "in the frontend there is no connecting to the categorie side bar" mean?

Comment: The widget woo category sidebar is empty. After refreshing only one product in the backend per category, the category sidebar in the frontend has entries.

Comment: It could be transients. Try going to WooCommerce>System Status>Tools. Then click the "clear transients" button. If that works, then you need to find a way to delete transients after your cronjob is done.

Comment: Thanks a lot Helga! But i need a php code for save/update/refresh a product, which I can insert in the cronjob task at the woocommerce backend.

Comment: I insert products with a php-script. posts and postmeta are filled correct. The product is also linked to the category. But the category sidebar widget wich is placed at the frontend doesn't display the categories with the quantity of the products, who are in this category. If I press the save/refresh button from only one product, this product and all the other products of the cat are displayed at sidebar.